# Keep counting in Android even if Activity is destroyed

Tags: android, service

following situation: I have an app that simply starts a counter by clicking on the 'start'-button. Because of the lifecycle, the progress of this counter is deleted once the activity is changed or the app is closed.

What I want is that the counter keeps incrementing even if the App/Activity isn't active.
From what I know, i should use a Service to accomplish this.

My progress now: I created a service which can be started and stopped flawless. I just don't know how to let the service count and pass the counted value back to the App every second. Is the service or my idea the wrong approach?

Any idea that points me towards a solution is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are numberous ways to provide communication between the two: intents, binders, .. etc

Comment: Bind your service to the activity.

Comment: Since there is no guarantee that the Activity exists it is better that the activity polls your service on a regular interval. The service will be there as long as your Activity needs it.

Comment: Generally though I would recommend you to find a solution where you can save the start time and based on elapsed time calculate the counter regularely. But this assumes that your counting is based on time and not some external input.

Comment: i forgot to mention that the counter is based on time.

Comment: as long as it's based on time, you can pass the counter each time the activity needs it (from the service) and calculate it from there (and the service) and the same time, passing the counter every second must be really expensive